# How to do indexing of two join tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, bigdata

I have two very big tables for example tab1 and tab2 in Postgres. I need to perform join and group by operation on these tables, to make my query fast i need indexing. Is there any way how to use index over join and group by queries ?? (as I heard indexing is not possible over join and group by)

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: "indexing is not possible over join and group by", please check your sources. And use EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see the query plan. You could also post the query plan at http://explain.depesz.com to show us when you need help.

Comment: thanks, i think now i need to change in data model.